# Gradle equivalent of Surefire classpathDependencyExclude

Tags: java, maven, gradle, build, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm trying to migrate java project from maven to gradle. The problem is very tricky classpath dependency configuration for tests now.

Our maven-surefire-plugin configuration:

```
 <includes>
     <include>**/SomeTest1.java</include>
 </includes>
 <classpathDependencyExcludes>
     <classpathDependencyExclude>com.sun.jersey:jersey-core</classpathDependencyExclude>
 </classpathDependencyExcludes>
```

There are different classpathes for different test-classes. How can I implement it with Gradle?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all you need to differ your tests sources into separate sourceSets. Say, we need to run tests from package *org.foo.test.rest* with a little different runtime classpath, than other tests. Thus, its execution will go to **otherTest**, where remain tests are in **test**:

```
sourceSets {
    otherTest {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
            include 'org/foo/test/rest/**'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
            exclude 'org/foo/rest/test/**'
        }
        resources {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you should make sure that **otherTest** has all required compile and runtime classpaths set correctly:

```
otherTestCompile sourceSets.main.output
otherTestCompile configurations.testCompile
otherTestCompile sourceSets.test.output
otherTestRuntime configurations.testRuntime + configurations.testCompile
```

The last thing is to exclude (or include) unneeded runtime bundles from **test**:

```
configurations {
    testRuntime {
        exclude group: 'org.conflicting.library'
    }
}
```

And to create Test Gradle task for **otherTest**:

```
task otherTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.otherTest.output.classesDir
    classpath += sourceSets.otherTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check.dependsOn otherTest
```

Comment: I did so and got `> Could not find method otherTestCompile() for arguments [main classes] on project`. Any ideas what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Use next workaround:

1. Create source set for needed tests
2. Add configurations for created sourceSet
3. Add task for run test with custom configuration
4. Configure test task dependOn customized test task
5. Configure Report plugin for generate beautiful html report :)

Like this [getting started](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-integration-testing/)